# I have an arc I want to draw an arrow around which is animated just like the arc is

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

[image: Here is the image]

The arrow around the arc is what I want to draw

Here is the code for the animated arc.

The code I have added draws an animated arc to the point of touch on another arc. The arc fills up with the provided gradient color to the point of touch on the arc. The filling up of the arc is an animation. The code for the animation works. I want to draw an arrow around the arc which follows the arc to the point where it is filled. The end result has to be an arrow which follows the arc.

Please help me with this.

```
    //Rectangle for the arc
    private RectF mArcRect = new RectF();

    //Paints required for drawing
    private Paint mArcPaint;
    private Paint mArcProgressPaint;
    private Paint mTickPaint;
    private Paint mTickProgressPaint;
    private Paint mTickTextPaint;
    private Paint mTickTextColoredPaint;
    private Paint linePaint;


    //Arc related dimens
    private int mArcRadius = 0;
    private int mArcWidth = 2;
    private int mArcProgressWidth = 18;
    private boolean mRoundedEdges = true;

    //Thumb Drawable
    private Drawable mThumb;

    //Thumb position related coordinates
    private int mTranslateX;
    private int mTranslateY;
    private int mThumbXPos;
    private int mThumbYPos;

    private int mAngleTextSize = 12;
    private int LOWER_LIMIT = -16;

    private int mTickOffset = 12;
    private int mTickLength = 10;
    private int mTickWidth = 2;
    private int mTickProgressWidth = 2;
    private int mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
    private boolean mTouchInside = true;
    private boolean mEnabled = true;
    private TicksBetweenLabel mTicksBetweenLabel = TicksBetweenLabel.TWO;
    private int mTickIntervals = 15;
    private double mTouchAngle = 0;
    private float mTouchIgnoreRadius;
    private int sweepAngle = 0;
    private int oldAngle = 0;
    private int bottomLeft;
    private int top;
    private long startClickTime = 0;


    //Event listener
    private OnProtractorViewChangeListener mOnProtractorViewChangeListener = null;


    //Interface for event listener
    public interface OnProtractorViewChangeListener {
        void onProgressChanged(ProtractorView protractorView, double progress, boolean fromUser);

        void onStartTrackingTouch(ProtractorView protractorView);

        void onStopTrackingTouch(ProtractorView protractorView);
    }

    public enum TicksBetweenLabel {
        ZERO,
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
    }

    public ProtractorView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public ProtractorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, R.attr.protractorViewStyle);
    }

    public ProtractorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        final Resources res = getResources();


        int textColor = res.getColor(R.color.progress_gray);
        int textProgressColor = res.getColor(R.color.default_blue_light);
        int tickColor = res.getColor(R.color.progress_gray);
        int tickProgressColor = res.getColor(R.color.default_blue_light);
        int thumbHalfHeight;
        int thumbHalfWidth;

        mThumb = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb_selector);

        mArcWidth = (int)(mArcWidth * DENSITY);
        mArcProgressWidth = (int)(mArcProgressWidth * DENSITY);
        mAngleTextSize = (int)(mAngleTextSize * DENSITY);
        mTickOffset = (int)(mTickOffset * DENSITY);
        mTickLength = (int)(mTickLength * DENSITY);
        mTickWidth = (int)(mTickWidth * DENSITY);
        mTickProgressWidth = (int)(mTickProgressWidth * DENSITY);

        if (attrs != null) {
            final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProtractorView, defStyle, 0);
            Drawable thumb = array.getDrawable(R.styleable.ProtractorView_thumb);
            if (thumb != null) {
                mThumb = thumb;
            }
            thumbHalfHeight = mThumb.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;
            thumbHalfWidth = mThumb.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
            mThumb.setBounds(-thumbHalfWidth, -thumbHalfHeight, thumbHalfWidth, thumbHalfHeight);
            //Dimensions
            mAngleTextSize = (int) array.getDimension(R.styleable.ProtractorView_angleTextSize, mAngleTextSize);
            mArcProgressWidth = (int) array.getDimension(R.styleable.ProtractorView_progressWidth, mArcProgressWidth);
            mTickOffset = (int) array.getDimension(R.styleable.ProtractorView_tickOffset, mTickOffset);
            mTickLength = (int) array.getDimension(R.styleable.ProtractorView_tickLength, mTickLength);
            mArcWidth = (int) array.getDimension(R.styleable.ProtractorView_arcWidth, mArcWidth);
            //Integers
            mAngle = array.getInteger(R.styleable.ProtractorView_angle, mAngle);
            mTickIntervals = array.getInt(R.styleable.ProtractorView_tickIntervals, mTickIntervals);
            //Colors
            textColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.ProtractorView_textColor, textColor);
            textProgressColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.ProtractorView_textProgressColor, textProgressColor);
            tickColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.ProtractorView_tickColor, tickColor);
            tickProgressColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.ProtractorView_tickProgressColor, tickProgressColor);
            //Boolean
            mRoundedEdges = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.ProtractorView_roundEdges, mRoundedEdges);
            mEnabled = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.ProtractorView_enabled, mEnabled);
            mTouchInside = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.ProtractorView_touchInside, mTouchInside);
            int ordinal = array.getInt(R.styleable.ProtractorView_ticksBetweenLabel, mTicksBetweenLabel.ordinal());
            mTicksBetweenLabel = TicksBetweenLabel.values()[ordinal];
        }

        /**
         * Creating and configuring the paints as  required.
         */
        mAngle = (mAngle > MAX) ? MAX : ((mAngle < 0) ? LOWER_LIMIT : mAngle);


        int[] colors = buildColorArray("60");
        mArcPaint = new Paint();
        mArcPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 550, 0, colors, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
        mArcPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mArcPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mArcPaint.setStrokeWidth(mArcWidth);

        int[] foregroundColors = buildColorArray("");
        mArcProgressPaint = new Paint();
        mArcProgressPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 550, 0, foregroundColors, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
        mArcProgressPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mArcProgressPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mArcProgressPaint.setStrokeWidth(mArcProgressWidth);

        if (mRoundedEdges) {
            mArcPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mArcProgressPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        }

        mTickPaint = new Paint();
        mTickPaint.setColor(tickColor);
        mTickPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTickPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mTickPaint.setStrokeWidth(mTickWidth);


        mTickProgressPaint = new Paint();
        mTickProgressPaint.setColor(tickProgressColor);
        mTickProgressPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTickProgressPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mTickProgressPaint.setStrokeWidth(mTickProgressWidth);

        mTickTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTickTextPaint.setColor(textColor);
        mTickTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTickTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mTickTextPaint.setTextSize(mAngleTextSize);
        mTickTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        mTickTextColoredPaint = new Paint();
        mTickTextColoredPaint.setColor(textProgressColor);
        mTickTextColoredPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTickTextColoredPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mTickTextColoredPaint.setTextSize(mAngleTextSize);
        mTickTextColoredPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        linePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    private int[] buildColorArray(String alpha) {
        //#ffc0c0
        //#fd708a
        //#54fcff
        //        String [] colors = {"#" + alpha + "60f0f6", "#" + alpha + "fd708a", "#" + alpha + "fd708a", "#" + alpha + "60f0f6", "#" + alpha + "d683a0", "#" + alpha + "60f0f6"};
        String[] colors = {
            "#" + alpha + "60f0f6",
            "#" + alpha + "69dee9",
            "#" + alpha + "99bbcd",
            "#" + alpha + "fd708a",
            "#" + alpha + "f8849b"
        };
        int[] colorValues = new int[colors.length]; //#59dae1
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            colorValues[j++] = Color.parseColor(colors[i]); //60f0f6, 54fcff, fd708a
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Color value: " + colors[i]);
            }
        }
        return colorValues;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(),
            heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
            widthMeasureSpec);
        int min = Math.min(width, height);
        //width = min;
        height = min / 2;
        int arcDiameter = 0;

        int tickEndToArc = (mTickOffset + mTickLength);

        int radiusConstant = 30;

        arcDiameter = min - 2 * tickEndToArc + radiusConstant;
        arcDiameter = (int)(arcDiameter - 2 * 20 * DENSITY);
        mArcRadius = arcDiameter / 2;


        top = height - (mArcRadius);
        bottomLeft = width / 2 - mArcRadius;

        mArcRect.set(bottomLeft, top, bottomLeft + arcDiameter, top + arcDiameter);

        mTranslateX = (int) mArcRect.centerX();
        mTranslateY = (int) mArcRect.centerY();


        int thumbAngle = mAngle;
        mThumbXPos = (int)(mArcRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(thumbAngle)));
        mThumbYPos = (int)(mArcRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(thumbAngle)));
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "co ordinate  =  x = " + mThumbXPos + " y = " + mThumbYPos + " mAngle = " + mAngle);
        }
        setTouchInside(mTouchInside);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height + tickEndToArc + 33);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mAngle > 0) {
            mAngle = mAngle - 360;
        }
        if (mAngle <= 0 && mAngle > LOWER_LIMIT) {
            mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
        }
        if (mTouchAngle > START_ANGLE && mTouchAngle < THRESHOLD_VALUE) {
            mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
        }
        sweepAngle = mAngle;
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The Sweep Angle is : " + sweepAngle);
        }
        if (sweepAngle < -280) {
            mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
        }
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Max angle " + mAngle);
        }
        if ((double)(mAngle / 13) > 19) {
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside If condition to set Complete angle");
            }
            mAngle = COMPLETE_ANGLE;
        }
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(1, -1, mArcRect.centerX(), mArcRect.centerY());
        canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, 0, MAX, false, mArcPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, (int) START_ANGLE, mAngle, false, mArcProgressPaint);
        canvas.restore();


        double slope, startTickX, startTickY, endTickX, endTickY, midTickX, midTickY, thetaInRadians;
        double radiusOffset = mArcRadius + mTickOffset;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        if (mThumb != null && mThumb.isStateful()) {
            int[] state = getDrawableState();
            mThumb.setState(state);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mEnabled) {
            this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (ignoreTouch(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (ignoreAngleTouch(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    onStartTrackingTouch();
                    oldAngle = getAngle();
                    if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: ACTION_DOWN old angle" + getAngle());
                    }
                    startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                    updateOnTouch(event);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_MOVE TRIGGERED");
                    }
                    if (ignoreAngleTouch(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    updateOnTouchForMove(event);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    onStopTrackingTouch();
                    if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: ACTION_UP old angle" + getAngle());
                    }
                    long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                    if (clickDuration > 50) {
                        updateOnTouchForMove(event);
                    } else {
                        updateOnTouch(event);
                    }
                    setPressed(false);
                    this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    onStopTrackingTouch();
                    setPressed(false);
                    this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean ignoreAngleTouch(float x, float y) {
        boolean ignore = false;
        double touchAngle = getTouchDegrees(x, y);
        if (touchAngle > START_ANGLE && touchAngle < LOWER_THRESHOLD_VALUE || touchAngle > START_ANGLE && touchAngle < THRESHOLD_VALUE) {
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ignoreAngleTouch");
            }
            ignore = true;
        }
        return ignore;
    }

    private void updateOnTouchForMove(MotionEvent event) {
        setPressed(true);
        mTouchAngle = getTouchDegrees(event.getX(), event.getY());
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Touch Angle " + mTouchAngle);
        }
        int angle = (int) mTouchAngle - (int) START_ANGLE;
        updateAngleForMove(angle);
    }

    private void updateAngleForMove(int angle) {
        mAngle = (angle > MAX) ? angle : (angle < 0) ? angle : angle;
        if (angle == 0) {
            mAngle = (int) START_ANGLE;
        }
        int cloneAngle = mAngle;
        if (mTouchAngle > START_ANGLE && mTouchAngle < LOWER_THRESHOLD_VALUE) {
            mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
        }
        if ((mAngle / 13) > 19) {
            mAngle = COMPLETE_ANGLE;
        }
        if (mOnProtractorViewChangeListener != null) {
            mOnProtractorViewChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, cloneAngle, true);
        }
        boolean check = mTouchAngle > START_ANGLE && mTouchAngle < THRESHOLD_VALUE;
        if (!check) {
            updateThumbPosition();
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "updateAngle: Re Drawing");
            }
            invalidate();
        } else {
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside else condition");
            }
            mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
            updateThumbPosition();
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void onStartTrackingTouch() {
        if (mOnProtractorViewChangeListener != null) {
            mOnProtractorViewChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
        }
    }

    private void onStopTrackingTouch() {
        if (mOnProtractorViewChangeListener != null) {
            mOnProtractorViewChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
        }
    }

    private boolean ignoreTouch(float xPos, float yPos) {
        boolean ignore = false;
        float x = xPos - mTranslateX;
        float y = yPos - mTranslateY;

        float touchRadius = (float) Math.sqrt(((x * x) + (y * y)));
        if (touchRadius < mTouchIgnoreRadius + 30 || touchRadius > (mArcRadius + mTickLength + mTickOffset)) {
            ignore = true;
        }
        return ignore;
    }

    private void updateOnTouch(MotionEvent event) {
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "updateOnTouch: Old Angle" + getAngle());
        }
        boolean ignoreTouch = ignoreTouch(event.getX(), event.getY());
        if (ignoreTouch) {
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "in ignore touch");
            }
            return;
        }
        setPressed(true);
        mTouchAngle = getTouchDegrees(event.getX(), event.getY());
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Touch Angle " + mTouchAngle);
        }
        int angle = (int) mTouchAngle - (int) START_ANGLE;
        onProgressRefresh(angle, true);
    }

    private double getTouchDegrees(float xPos, float yPos) {
        float x = xPos - mTranslateX;
        float y = yPos - mTranslateY;
        x = -x;
        // convert to arc Angle
        double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x) + (Math.PI));
        /*if (angle > 270)
            angle = 0;
        else if (angle > 180)
            angle = 360;*/
        return angle;
    }

    private void onProgressRefresh(int angle, boolean fromUser) {
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Change Angle: " + angle);
        }
        updateAngle(angle, fromUser);
    }

    private void updateAngle(int angle, boolean fromUser) {
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "updateAngle: " + angle);
        }
        mAngle = (angle > MAX) ? angle : (angle < 0) ? angle : angle;
        if (angle == 0) {
            mAngle = (int) START_ANGLE;
        }
        if (mAngle > LOWER_LIMIT && mAngle < 0) {
            mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
        }
        if (mTouchAngle > START_ANGLE && mTouchAngle < THRESHOLD_VALUE) {
            mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
        }
        int cloneAngle = mAngle;
        if (mAngle > 0) {
            cloneAngle = mAngle - 360;
        }
        if ((mAngle / 13) > 19) {
            mAngle = COMPLETE_ANGLE;
        }
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "updateAngle: Angle being sent to onProgressChanged " + cloneAngle);
        }
        if (mOnProtractorViewChangeListener != null) {
            mOnProtractorViewChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, cloneAngle, true);
        }
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Angle being sent to the function = " + mAngle);
        }
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Value of Sweep Angle " + sweepAngle);
        }
        boolean check = mTouchAngle > START_ANGLE && mTouchAngle < THRESHOLD_VALUE;
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Check Condition Value: " + check);
        }
        if (!check) {
            updateThumbPosition();
            if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "updateAngle: Re Drawing");
            }
            startAnimatingArc();
        } else {
            mAngle = LOWER_LIMIT;
            updateThumbPosition();
            startAnimatingArc();
        }
    }

    public void startAnimatingArc() {
        final ProtractorView protractorView = findViewById(R.id.protractorview);
        if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside start Animating Arc\nOld Angle: " + getOldAngle() + "\nNew Angle: " + getAngle());
        }


        int newAngle = getAngle();
        if (newAngle > 0) {
            newAngle -= 360;
        }

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(getOldAngle(), newAngle);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                int animatedValue = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                if (Util.IS_DEBUG_LOGGABLE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationUpdate: Animated Value " + animatedValue);
                }
                mAngle = animatedValue;
                protractorView.invalidate();
            }
        });
        animator.setDuration(450);
        animator.start();
        //        invalidate();
    }


    private void updateThumbPosition() {
        int thumbAngle = mAngle; //(int) (mStartAngle + mProgressSweep + mRotation + 90);
        mThumbXPos = (int)(mArcRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(thumbAngle)));
        mThumbYPos = (int)(mArcRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(thumbAngle)));
    }


    //*****************************************************
    // Setters and Getters
    //*****************************************************

    public boolean getTouchInside() {
        return mTouchInside;
    }

    public void setTouchInside(boolean isEnabled) {
        int thumbHalfheight = mThumb.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;
        int thumbHalfWidth = mThumb.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
        mTouchInside = isEnabled;
        if (mTouchInside) {
            mTouchIgnoreRadius = (float)(mArcRadius / 1.5) + 5;
        } else {
            mTouchIgnoreRadius = mArcRadius + 5 - Math.min(thumbHalfWidth, thumbHalfheight);
        }
    }

    public void setOnProtractorViewChangeListener(OnProtractorViewChangeListener l) {
        mOnProtractorViewChangeListener = l;
    }

    public OnProtractorViewChangeListener getOnProtractorViewChangeListener() {
        return mOnProtractorViewChangeListener;
    }

    public int getAngle() {
        return mAngle;
    }

    public void setAngle(int angle) {
        this.mAngle = angle;
        onProgressRefresh(mAngle, false);
    }

    public int getOldAngle() {
        return oldAngle;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return mEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.mEnabled = enabled;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getProgressColor() {
        return mArcProgressPaint.getColor();
    }

    public void setProgressColor(@ColorInt int color) {
        mArcProgressPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getArcColor() {
        return mArcPaint.getColor();
    }

    public void setArcColor(@ColorInt int color) {
        mArcPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getArcProgressWidth() {
        return mArcProgressWidth;
    }

    public void setArcProgressWidth(int arcProgressWidth) {
        this.mArcProgressWidth = arcProgressWidth;
        mArcProgressPaint.setStrokeWidth(arcProgressWidth);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getArcWidth() {
        return mArcWidth;
    }

    public void setArcWidth(int arcWidth) {
        this.mArcWidth = arcWidth;
        mArcPaint.setStrokeWidth(arcWidth);
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isRoundedEdges() {
        return mRoundedEdges;
    }

    public void setRoundedEdges(boolean roundedEdges) {
        this.mRoundedEdges = roundedEdges;
        if (roundedEdges) {
            mArcPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mArcProgressPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        } else {
            mArcPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
            mArcPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public Drawable getThumb() {
        return mThumb;
    }

    public void setThumb(Drawable thumb) {
        this.mThumb = thumb;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getAngleTextSize() {
        return mAngleTextSize;
    }

    public void setAngleTextSize(int angleTextSize) {
        this.mAngleTextSize = angleTextSize;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getTickOffset() {
        return mTickOffset;
    }

    public void setTickOffset(int tickOffset) {
        this.mTickOffset = tickOffset;
    }

    public int getTickLength() {
        return mTickLength;
    }

    public void setTickLength(int tickLength) {
        this.mTickLength = tickLength;
    }

    public TicksBetweenLabel getTicksBetweenLabel() {
        return mTicksBetweenLabel;
    }

    public void setTicksBetweenLabel(TicksBetweenLabel ticksBetweenLabel) {
        this.mTicksBetweenLabel = mTicksBetweenLabel;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getTickIntervals() {
        return mTickIntervals;
    }

    public void setTickIntervals(int tickIntervals) {
        this.mTickIntervals = tickIntervals;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you drawing `mThumb`?

Comment: mThumb is not being used yet. It will be used later.

Comment: ok so what problems do you have with drawing your arrow? is it a `Path` or something?

Comment: I do not know how to draw the arrow.

Comment: use `Canvas#drawPath` for example

Comment: I tried it but was not able to get it right because the arrow does not come around the circle. Plus it repeats multiple times as it overlaps its previous instances. It is not animated like the filling up of the arc.

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/KttW4y6b

Comment: The arc is already a different view. How do I add the second view?

Comment: what for? just do your drawing in one custom view - you have the code for arrow drawing, so add it to your custom view